# How to download previous kaa versions

Tags: kaa

I want to download a previous kaa version on the format of the sandbox image, I have searched everywhere but I didn't find these files to download. Does anybody know if they are still available?

Answer (score 0):

Historically, the Kaa site provides download option for the latest release only.

Anyway, the previous versions of Kaa Sandbox are available and can be provided by a request. Please use 'Contact us' option on the [Kaa Web site](https://www.kaaproject.org/) to request Kaa Sandbox download link (please specify the version(s) you are interested in).

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. I did that on beginning of last week. But I got no answer back. I am having several problems with the new version which I did not have on version 0.9.0, so I really need the previous version.